# quickbooks 2017 enterprise on windows server 2016 fail to turn on .net framework 4.6 feature

Tags: .net-framework, quickbooks, windows-server-2016

upon installing QB2017 Enterprise on windows server 20146, QB Database Manager will crash when scanning folders, here is what I can manage to find out.

QB diagnostic:

```
 fail to turn on .net framework 4.6 feature
```

I turn on all framework 4.6 feature using "add feature/role", the error still persist.

I get the following error event

> Application: QBServerUtilityMgr.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException
>      at NetworkRepairCore.QBConnectivity._UtilGetPrivateProfileInt(System.String, System.String, Int32, System.String, System.String, Int32)
>      at NetworkRepairCore.QBConnectivity.GetDBPort(Int32)
>      at NetworkRepairCore.QBConnectivity.Init(System.String, Int32, Int32)
>      at NetworkRepairCore.NetworkRepair.CheckNetworkAccessToFile()
>      at Intuit.SBM.DataHelper.QBServerUtilityMgr.MainForm.NWRepair_Worker_DoWork(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(System.Object)
>
> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>      at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>      at Intuit.SBM.DataHelper.QBServerUtilityMgr.MainForm.NWRepair_Worker_Completed(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>      at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>
> Faulting application name: QBServerUtilityMgr.exe, version: 20.0.6181.35176, time stamp: 0x5842d079
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.479, time stamp: 0x58256d37
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Fault offset: 0x000da832
>   Faulting process id: 0x15c8
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d282f9b0a9e8cb
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\QBServerUtilityMgr.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 277158a3-e2b0-4b26-b396-410395fb9947
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: The software requires specifically .NET Framework 4.0 and you have .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed.  You need to install, `.NET Framework 4.5.2` which is an in-place upgrade to .NET Framework 4.0, if you want your application to work.  [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yeah, but the problem is I am on Win Server 2016, is that fixable?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  This might seem like a silly question, but the website seems clear to me, of course the layout of the table is slightly off also.

Comment: Yes.  I did,  it said that 2016 can not install other version.  Unless I am reading it wrong.  At least not officially supported.